# Why 0 and null are true and false with equal operator?

Tags: javascript, null, conditional-statements

I want to ask about a weird javascript thing. All of these conditions, in my opinion, contradict each other and return false:

- 0 > null
- 0 < null
- 0 == null
- 0 === null

Why does using >= and <= operators return true? >= means gt and <= means lt. They couldn’t be equals. Moreover, “null” has a null value, 0 has a null value and, for the logic 0 > null should return true. Could someone explain me this fact?

Comment: All these values are false. And rightly so. Because they ARE quite obviously false. Simply because 0 and null are treated as false in an if construct does not mean that these values are equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @mattew.  JavaScript operators are a very common source of puzzlement to people new to the language and most of their oddness revolves around the concept of `type coercion`.  I've linked you to one question here that covers that question some.  If you google for the phrase `javascript type coercion` you will come across page after page of explanations.

Comment: jeremy and rexell, my question is different.

Comment: >= and <= don't mean gt and lt. They are the best JavaScript equivalents (because it was designed for ASCII-only) for ≥ and ≤, respectively.

Comment: The answer provided by @raxell answers your question exactly, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Mattew `null` is coerced to Number. `Number(null)` is zero, so 0 >= 0 is obviously true, while 0 > 0 is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `>` and `<`, `null` is converted to the number `0`. `0 > 0` and `0 < 0` are both `false` (that's basic math). When you use `==` and `===`, `null` **is not** converted. `0` is not equal to `null` and hence both are `false` as well.

More generally speaking: Operators are defined for specific *data types* and if you pass a value of a different data type that value will be converted to the expected data type first. `>` and `<` are defined for *strings* and *numbers* but not for `null`. Hence `null` is (eventually) converted to a number.

`==` are a little different `===`. While `==` usually performs type conversion, it doesn't do that if you compare against `null`. That's simply [how the algorithm works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491302/why-0-and-null-are-true-and-false-with-equal-operator/).